# how to re-render fullcalendar while filtering from parent view

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar-5

I want to render calendar events based on the values selected in filter. My filter controls are in parent view and my calendar is in partial view.

I'm calling MVC controller below:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_Filter", "Calendar", new AjaxOptions() { 
            HttpMethod = "Get", 
            OnSuccess= "events(data)", }, 
            new { @class = "form-inline"}))
```

My success function is:

```
function events(data) {
            eventdata = [];
            var $calendar = $('#calendar');
            response.forEach(function (index) {
                eventdata.push(index);
            })
            $calendar.addEventSource(eventdata, true);
            $calendar.refetchEvents();
        }
```

I'm getting the filtered value in **data**. My calendar disappear while entering into this function and also i'm getting the below error[image]

Below is my calendar code:

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
    <!-- The script to initialize the calendar-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
events: function (start, sucessCallback, ErrorCallback) {
                    eventdata = [];
                                var sDate = moment(start.startStr).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
                                var eDate = moment(start.endStr).format('MM-DD-YYYY');

                    $.get("/Calendar/_Events?start=" + sDate + "&end=" + eDate, function (data) {
                    })
                        .done(function (data) {
                                $.each(response, function(index, row) {
                                        eventdata.push(row);
                                    });
                                    successCallback(eventdata);
                                })
                            .fail(function(err) {
                                });
                    }
                }
 calendar.render(); 
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You use tag ist with fullcalendar-5.
But since 4.x fullcalendar don't support JQuery.

So

```
var $calendar = $('#calendar');
$calendar.addEventSource(eventdata, true);
```

could not work anymore. Thats whats the Error also exacly says.

Replace it by

```
 var calendarEl = document.getElementById('bootstrapModalFullCalendar'); 
 var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, { ...
 calendar.addEventSource(eventdata); // not  second Paramenter!
 calendar.refetchEvents();
```

(But of cause you can use JQuery inside your functions.)

Also a lot of other things change, so please may read the docs of 5.x